# How can i submit inputs located inside the <div style="display:none">?

Tags: php, jquery, html, dom

The case :

```
<form  id='frm' name ='frm' action='test.php'>
 <div style='display:none'>
 <input type='text' name='name' value ='' />
 </div>
 <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

For example , How can i submit the from given above with its inputs ?
Issue :  The "name" input wont be passed !

Comment: `The "name" input wont be passed !` Yes it will.

Answer (score 6):

Programatically, you can just trigger the [`submit`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit) event on the form element:

```
$('#frm').submit();
```

**Edit:** Actually, after reading your markup more *carefully*, you are using an `input` named `name`, this element can cause "clashing" problems with the form's name attribute.

Consider changing the name of your input.

See also:

- [Unsafe Names for HTML Form Controls](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/names/)

Answer (score 3):

As a user, you'd just **click the submit button.** The visibility of a form element doesn't change the fact that it gets submitted with the form.

Programmatically:

```
document.getElementById('frm').submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not trying to show the input, why not use type="hidden" and dispense with the style?

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('frm').submit();`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to submit hidden variables in a FORM:

```
<input type='hidden' name='name' value ='' />
```